# QGIS 3.6 and QGIS 3.10 report different geometry types for the same shapefile

Tags: python, pyqgis

I used QGIS 3.6.3 to create a polyline shapefile, and the program reported the polyline as `LineStringZM`. When I opened the same shape file in QGIS 3.10.3-2, the polyline was reported as `MultiLineStringZM`. (The geometry type can be found by right-clicking the shapefile on the Layers panel, then "Properties", then "Information", then under "Geometry")

I am confused why the same polyline can be `LinestringZM` or `MultiLinestringZM` when opened in different versions of program?  Did I do something wrong when creating the polyline?  This is important to me, because I use python to process the polyline and different geometry type would require different coding. My code is able to process the shapefile in QGIS 3.6.3, but gags when used in QGIS 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

Shapefile does not distinct LineStrings and MultiLineStrings. The corresponding shapefile type is PolyLine https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf.

> **PolyLine** A PolyLine is an ordered set of vertices that consists of one or more parts. A part is a connected sequence of two or more
> points. Parts may or may not be connected to one another. Parts may or
> may not intersect one another.

BTW the same applies to Polygons/MultiPolygons but Points and MultiPoints are different shape types and cannot be saved into a same shapefile.

QGIS makes a difference between LineStrings and MultiLineStrings. Because a LineString is possible to express as a single part MultiLineString, but MultiLineString cannot be expressed as a LineString, it is safest to consider that all lines in a shapefile are MultiLineStrings. Even if a shapefile does not contain any MultiLineStrings, it might contain such. Also, if the QGIS user wants to digitize a MultiLineString and save it into shapefile format that can be done, but only when the QGIS layer is defined to be MultiLineString.

If separating LineStrings and MultiLineStrings in the Python code is important, it is possible to filter them with `wkbType()` https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html.

Answer (score 0):

That is kind of weird because shapefile does not support MultiLineStrings, the type is Polyline which is single.

Anyway, to make more robust your code you can always convert the geometry to single, using `convertToSingleType` ([QGIS Docs - Geometry convertToSingleType](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.convertToSingleType)), before using it. This function don't do anything if it is already single.

Comment: Currently I use isMultipart() to first test the geometry type to determine how to proceed with the polyline processing in the code. The Python program becomes a little longer, but allows me to use the same code and shape file in both 3.6 and 3.10 versions.